# iptable rule for an IP address with "any" subnet mask

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

I have a **requirement** to add an iptable rule for lets say src IP 10.10.10.20/any dest IP any.

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD_0_IN -p all --ipv4 --source 10.10.10.1/any --destination 10.10.10.2/any  -j DROP
```

Above command fails with error:
iptables v1.8.6 (legacy): invalid mask `any' specified

This `/any` implies all possible subnet masks `/0 to /32`.
I want to avoid adding individual 33 rules for each subnet mask.
What is a better way to achieve this ?

Till then let me get it clarified from requirements team, what is expectation with /any.

Comment: Why would you want to add all masks? The mask `/0` means any address so it covers all other masks.

Comment: Yes, even I thought so, /0 would mean any IP. Let me get the requirement clear from my Team.

Comment: Just simple **ommiting** `--source b.l.a.h` would mean "any IP", e.g. the same thing as /0 mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to avoid adding individual 33 rules for each subnet mask.

It is very unlikely that you would ever need to that. And I think you don't quite understand what a subnet mask means or effects.

A very long Q&A is this one: [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

But very simplified:

When you add an  IPv4 IP-address without any subnet subnet mask or with an /32 subnet mask that means *"this particular IP-address"*.

When you use an IPv4 IP-address with *any* other subnet mask than `/32`  that means: *"the [CIDR subnet range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) that includes this IP-address"*.

In other words `10.10.10.1/24` means: *"the /24 subnet range that includes `10.10.10.1`"*
i.e. the subnet ranging from `10.10.10.0` to `10.10.10.255`  which is more commonly specified as `10.10.10.0/24`

Subsequently  `10.10.10.1/8` means: *"the /8 range that includes `10.10.10.1`"*
i.e. the subnet ranging from `10.0.0.0` to `10.255.255.255`  ; which is normally specified as `10.0.0.0/8` but `10.10.10.1/8` is equivalent.

Note that such a range includes `10.10.10.1/9` , `10.10.10.1/10` , `10.10.10.1/11`  .... and all subnets until `10.10.10.1/32`

And `10.10.10.1/0` means: *"the /0 range that includes `10.10.10.1`"*   - that is the range from `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255` or in other words  ***any IPv4 address***.

Comment: Yes, I know about subnet masks, and I too am confused with /any requirement. Let me get it clarified from my requirements team. I thought /any is some standard term used in the industry and has some special meaning.

Comment: I got it clarified, they meant /any = /32.

Comment: This is very strange "clarification", because /32 in context of a firewall means "to match a single host". I can't imagine any circumstances of how "all" might appear there in this meaning, other than blatant incompetence.

Answer (score 0):

IP address doesn't have a property of a "subnet mask". (It had, in the distant past of classful addressing, but these times are long long gone — more than 30 years ago, with the inception of a CIDR. You should forget about that and pretend this never was the case. Also, the rest of the answer is still valid even in case of classful addressing).

So, IP address is just 32 bits number and by seeing just an IP address you can't tell what mask it was configured with on the system where it is assigned. The mask has some meaning to that system only — it is meant to tell that system which addresses are reachable "immediately" and which ones it needs to access through the gateway. Netmask is a **routing** feature; the only effect it has is to define certain "connected"-type route.

It is **meaningless** requirement to "allow certain IP with any mask".

---

Probably this notation in your requirement was meant to be not a mask, but a port number? Then it needs a L4 protocol to be specified (TCP, UDP, etc.) which has a concept of port numbers. Or, this could have been a protocol itself, meaning "any" IP protocol number from that host should be permitted.